# Liferay: change the /guest word to something else

Tags: liferay-6

Is it possible to change the 'guest' word in "/web/guest/home" to something else, eg. LR? I am using liferay 6.1.

UPDATE: I have tried to change this through Control panel -> Site settings -> Site URL, but didn't work. Also wrote company.default.home.url=/LR in the portal properties file, that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

You can search via internet.
You can do it: http://www.mygeekjourney.com/index.php/2012/05/21/how-to-remove-web-guest-in-liferay-6-1/

Comment: Actually tried changing that through control panel before coming here, but didn't work that way.

Comment: This may help you:https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4233941

Comment: Unfortunately none of thise helped. I have actually tried many solutions found on Internet, but no success :(

Comment: I don't know your configuration, with me that work. Did you try post in liferay'forum ? in other way, you can use .htaccess file !

Comment: + 1, virtual host is the way to do that. And the given link should work. Maybe you've done something wrong setting that up, like your virtual host not matching the actual url. Try to make your your portal work with a url different than 'localhost' first, then use the virtual host feature